# check access permission in fuelphp

Tags: permissions, fuelphp

I am new to fuelphp, please help me with this problem. Currently, in users_permissions table I have this row:

```
id  area    permission  description actions user_id created_at  updated_at
1   member  detail                              1       0           0
```

Below is the written code in the controller

```
if (\Auth::has_access('member.detail'))
    $data['temp'] = "yeah";
else
    $data['temp'] = "no";
```

What I am trying to do is to give the access member.detail to user with id 1. But the result is always equals to "no".

Comment: Did you clear permission cache? Did you set ormauth correctly up?

Comment: @mark.sagikazar I think I set ormauth correctly...but permission cache clearance... maybe not. Would you mind explaining more about this. Is it written here: http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/auth/ormauth/intro.html at caching?

Comment: Yeah, I am talking abot that. Look into the cache folder in your application...

Comment: I cleared the cache but still couldn't make it work. Thanks for your help anyway @mark.sagikazar. I will try something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed defining the relation.

The permissions table just defines the permissions, the area, permission, and a possible array of valid actions. Before this takes effect, you have to assign this permission to something. This might be a user (direct assigned permission), or a group or a role to which the user is assigned. These are all many-to-many relations.

So assuming your user has id 1, you need an entry in the users_user_permissions "relation|junction|through" table, relating the two records:

```
id  user_id  perms_id actions
1         1         1
```

Now flush your auth cache, so the users effective rights are re-calculated, and it should work.